# Clear jQuery click queue

Tags: jquery

I have the function:

```
$(function(){
  $("#mydiv").click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('positive')) {
    $(this).delay(400).animate({right:'-210px'},1000)
          .addClass('negative').removeClass('positive')
} else {
    $(this).delay(400).animate({right:'10px'},1000)
          .addClass('positive').removeClass('negative')  
}
 }).clearQueue()
});
```

But if I click on my div a thousand times, it will execute the animation a thousand times.
I tried to shop around on Jquery API documentation but nither `.clearQueue()` (as in the function) nor `.stop(true)` seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use `stop(true)` before the `delay()` call. The following should do what you want:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('positive')) {
        $(this)
            .addClass('negative')
            .removeClass('positive')
            .stop(true)
            .delay(400)
            .animate({ right: '-210px' }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this)
            .addClass('positive')
            .removeClass('negative')
            .stop(true)
            .delay(400)
            .animate({ right: '10px' }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7htL9qsm/).

Comment: Fantastic! I just don't get the logic. Why does .stop() need to be placed right there and doesn't work if I place it after the delay?

Comment: If you place it after the delay, then it waits the 400ms before calling `stop()`. Looking at your example above, for instance, you only call `clearQueue()` once (when creating the handler) and not every time `#mydiv` is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You should unbind your element on the start of your handler.
And when the animation is ready bind the  handler again.

```
$(function(){
   $("#mydiv")click(function stg(e){
       var elem=$(e.target);
       elem.off('click',stg);
       if ($(this).hasClass('positive')) {
           $(this).delay(400)
                  .animate(
                    {right:'-210px'
                    ,complete:function(){elem.on('click',stg)}
                   },1000)
                  .addClass('negative').removeClass('positive')
       } else {
           $(this).delay(400)
                  .animate(
                    {right:'10px'
                    ,complete:function(){elem.on('click',stg)}
                    },1000)
                 .addClass('positive').removeClass('negative')  
       }
  })
});
```

The complete callback is only needed if you want to animate the element again after the animation.

Comment: Applying the class changes after the `delay()` is not going to give the results expected.

Comment: Edited my answer. any development?